# How to select two columns using their indices - GetRangeList

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using this helper function to get indices of columns by their header.

```
function getColByName(name){
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange().getValues().shift();
  var colindex = headers.indexOf(name);
  return colindex+1;
}
```

I store them in variables. For example column C has the header Driver Name and the variable will store the index 3. I do this so I can still reference that column (Driver Name) if it shifts locations in the spreadsheet. I would like to rewrite this line of code to reference columns C and E by that variable containing the index.

```
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['C:C', 'E:E']).activate();
```

Basically I want the getRangeList to get the Driver Name column without using the letter C (since it might change letters). I saw the getRangeList can use A1 and R1C1 notation so I am unsure if the helper function I am currently using will work.

Currently I reference a whole column like

```
getRange(1,C,maxrow)
```

where `maxrow = getMaxRows();`

Answer (score 1):

```
const headerA=sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
let hObj={};
headerA.forEach(function(h,i){hObj[h]=i});

now hObj['ColumnName'] returns index and if you want column number then add one.
```